# how to include unsupported jvm options in java web start?

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp, jvm-arguments

I have a java web start application that takes some parameters via .jnlp file, does some analysis, and uploads the results back to the server.  It works fine as long as I run it from NetBeans using

> -Dcom.sun.security.enableAIAcaIssuers=true

in the VM Options area.

But it doesn't work when running from the web page, launched like this:

```
deployJava.launchWebStartApplication('jws/CreoDimExtractor.jnlp');
```

It runs successfully until it gets to the upload section, then it fails with

> "javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to 
>   find valid certification path to requested target"

In my .jnlp file, I have included the JVM option like this:

```
<resources>
        <!-- Application Resources -->
        <j2se version="1.7+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" java-vm-args="-Dcom.sun.security.enableAIAcaIssuers=true"/>
        <jar href="En360_SFtp.jar" main="true" />
</resources>
```

and I have security set to:

```
<security><all-permissions/></security>
```

I read [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html) that

> "New secure properties can also be defined as needed by prefixing the
>   property name with "jnlp." or "javaws."."

So I also tried

```
<resources>
        <!-- Application Resources -->
        <j2se version="1.7+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" java-vm-args="-Djnlp.com.sun.security.enableAIAcaIssuers=true"/>
        <jar href="En360_SFtp.jar" main="true" />
</resources>
```

Neither of them worked.  I also read that

> The property element defines a system property that will be available
>   through the System.getProperty and System.setProperties methods. It
>   has two required attributes: name and value.

So in my java web start application I included these lines:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(params);
Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
env.put("com.sun.security.enableAIAcaIssuers","true");
```

But that didn't work either.  I'm out of ideas.  Any help?